# Embed HTML into application

Tags: android, android-layout

I have android application that is written "regular" way. layouts, java, APK.

Now, depending on some factors I want data to be presented differently to different users with different preferences, etc. Doing it using XML layouts will be very problematic in couple of reasons:

1. Upgrade issue - we have bunch of users and they not good at upgrading.
2. Hard to maintain and code.

So, I'm toying with idea of "templates" where we can serve templates from server and just use device to generate those.

1. Web app won't work because our data available offline in case there is no connection.
2. There is buttons and stuff that user can press to call regular Activities and do things.

I envision something like:
HTML 5 template with {tags} that I will populate from data. I will receive tempaltes and data separately from server. I will merge that data and display on UI.

Now my question is how do I:

1. Display HTML5 inside Activity
2. Intercept button push in HTML in my Java code?

Is this bad idea to write something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds reasonable to me. You can use a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for displaying the content. Your app can manage a cache of downloaded templates and other content and display it in the web view either from the web site or from the cache if offline.

Comment: Yes, I did research and I can put JavaScript on HTML and pass my object from Activity into DOM and handle Clicks/etc - so for some specific uses WebView will be excellent

Answer (score 0):

I think your objections to layouts are offbase. You really might be better off with layouts. Here's why:

Your app can be set to auto-update by users if you do not change permissions. But pushing updates to your app will remain an issue unless your app is entirely web-based. (not a bad approach by the way) But so long as you have a native app, you will need to push updates from time to time.

And as far as being hard to maintain and code, layouts are specifically designed to make this type of customization manageable. You can break pieces of the layout common to different settings into separate files, and add them with includes. 
You can use fragments to adapt to a variety of form factors. 
You can serve up different layout based on screen size, language, orientation, or any of a wide variety of variables.

Check out some of the series on layout tricks, and get more familiar with being a layout power user. I think in the long run it will save you a lot of effort, assuming you don't switch to making your app a web app instead.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/16/android-layout-tricks-4-optimize-part-2/

Google: Android Layout Tricks.
Great stuff.

Another benefit: Compiler checking. No broken functionality because a variable or field has the wrong name. Not the case with HTML.

Another benefit: works offline too with no messing around.

And last - you will have a non-trivial amount of work attempting to get this hybrid HTML stuff working the way you want, and then have a very unusual and custom code base that nobody here on Stack Overflow will be able to help you with. Stick with Layouts and there are lots of experts who can help you tackle the stickiest layout puzzles.

Comment: Well. Updating app from time to time is OK, but updating app with each UI tweak is a problem. Users of application(corporate users) have so many different ideas that it is easier to design HTML for them and store it somewhere so devices can adjust. I can't mauintain layouts for all possible desires and permutations. Yet, my app can't be 100% web based because of what it does. Plus, we support 2.1+ so Fragments is a tough call.